# Take specific rows from a csv file and put in an excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, csv

Good day,

I want to take some specific column(i.e column 3 and column 7) from a csv file and these two columns need to put into an output excel file.

I think that my issue is to put data in excel file.
The code that I tried to use is below.

```
import csv
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

file1=open('WebShop_Export_2016_Feb_19.csv','r')
readfile=csv.reader(file1,delimiter=';')
data=[]

wb=Workbook()
dest_filename = 'Name of OUPUT excel.xlsx'
ws = wb.active 
ws.title="Output XLSX"

for row in readfile:           
        data=row[2],row[6]  # take column 3 and 7 from source file
        print(data)# this line is just to see the info that will be put in the excel output
for row_index, item in enumerate(data):
            for column_index, cell in enumerate(item):
                column_letter = get_column_letter((column_index + 1))
                ws.cell('%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))).value = cell
file1.close()
wb.save('Name of OUPUT excel.xlsx')
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to append the contents of each row (e.g.`[row[2],row[6]]`) to `data` - at the moment you store it in `data`, i.e. overwriting what was there before so there is only a single entry in data when you try to put the values in the excel file. It may be even easier to output a two-column CSV file which Excel will open quite happily.

Comment: Now it's work.. Tkank you!